# Laravel query return wrong data

Tags: laravel

QUERY:

```php
$recent_posts = Blog::join("categories",'categories.id', '=', 'blogs.category_id')
    ->where('categories.status', 1)
    ->orderBy('blogs.id', 'desc')
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
```

Both tables had a created_at column.

At frontend im using this to retrieve the data:

```xml
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  @foreach ($recent_posts as $recent_post)
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 latest-blog-resp">
      <div class="blog-item">
        <div class="blog-img">
          <a href="{{ url('blog/'.$recent_post->slug) }}">
            @if ($recent_post->blog_image == '')
              <img src="{{ asset('fibonacci/adminpanel/assets/img/dummy/no_image.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid round-item" alt="blog image">
            @else
              <img src="{{ asset('fibonacci/adminpanel/assets/img/blog/thumbnail1/'.$recent_post->blog_image) }}" class="img-fluid round-item" alt="blog image">
            @endif
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-inner">
          <div class="blog-meta">
            <span class="mr-2">
              <i class="mdi mdi-calendar-account-outline"></i>{{ __('frontend.by_admin')  }}
            </span>
            <span>
              <i class="mdi mdi-calendar-range"></i>{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($recent_post->created_at)->isoFormat('MMMM')}} {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($recent_post->created_at)->isoFormat('DD')}}
            </span>
          </div>
          <h5 class="blog-title">
            <a href="{{ url('blog/'.$recent_post->slug) }}">{{ $recent_post->title }}</a>
          </h5>
          <p class="blog-desc">{{ $recent_post->short_description }}</p>
          <a href="{{ url('blog/'.$recent_post->slug) }}" class="blog-more-link">
            {{ __('frontend.read_more') }} <i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-2"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
  @if (count($recent_posts) === 3)
    <div class="col-12 text-center margin-top-30">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="{{ url('blog') }}"  class="default-button">
          {{ __('frontend.view_all') }}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endif
</div>
```

THE PROBLEM:
`$recent_post->created_at` returns the category table creation (created_at) date but we expect to receive the blog table result as created_as (like a post creation data).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When using join, you would need to select the fields you want and assign aliases where necessary. Laravel doesnt handle same column names well enough when using join.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your fields in a select clause.

```php
$recent_posts = Blog::select(
    'blogs.slug',
    'blogs.blog_image', 
    'blogs.title',
    'blogs.short_description',
    'blogs.created_at'
)
->join('categories', 'categories.id', 'blogs.category_id')
->where('categories.status', 1)
->orderByDesc('blogs.id')
->take(3)
->get();
```